# Base price, discounted price and percentage discount in the summary checkout

Tags: checkout, price, knockoutjs

I need to have the discounted, base, and percentage off prices in the summary checkout.
I found the file that prints and it is this checkout/summary/item/price/row_excl_tax.html but I can't retrieve the base price or even calculate the discount percentage on the item

[image: Location]

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, you can add the base price, discounted price, and percentage discount to the summary checkout by modifying the template files and creating a new block class. Here is an example of how you can do this:

1. Override the **`"checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml"`** layout file in your custom module. You can create a new directory called **`"Magento_Checkout"`** in the **`"view/frontend"`** directory of your custom module and create a new file called **`"layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml"`** within it.
2. In the **`"checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml"`** file, add the following code to add a new block to the summary checkout template:

Here is the code:-

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Checkout\Discount" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.discount" template="YourVendor_YourModule::checkout/discount.phtml" after="checkout.cart.item.renderers.name"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. Create a new block class called **`"Discount.php"`** in the **`"Block/Checkout"`** directory of your custom module.
4. In the **`"Discount.php"`** file, add the following code to define your new block class and retrieve the base price, discounted price, and percentage discount:

Here is the code:-

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Discount extends Template
{
    public function getDiscount()
    {
        $item = $this->getItem();
        $basePrice = $item->getPrice();
        $discountedPrice = $item->getDiscountAmount();
        $discountPercent = 0;
        if ($basePrice > 0) {
            $discountPercent = ($discountedPrice / $basePrice) * 100;
        }
        return [
            'base_price' => $basePrice,
            'discounted_price' => $discountedPrice,
            'discount_percent' => $discountPercent
        ];
    }
}
```

5. Create a new template file called **`"discount.phtml"`** in the **`"view/frontend/templates/checkout"`** directory of your custom module.
6. In the **`"discount.phtml"`** file, add the following code to display the base price, discounted price, and percentage discount in the summary checkout:

Here is the code:-

```
<?php
$discount = $block->getDiscount();
$basePrice = $discount['base_price'];
$discountedPrice = $discount['discounted_price'];
$discountPercent = $discount['discount_percent'];
?>
<div class="discount-info">
    <span>Base Price: <?php echo $basePrice ?></span>
    <span>Discounted Price: <?php echo $discountedPrice ?></span>
    <span>Discount Percent: <?php echo $discountPercent ?></span>
</div>
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**